# Change Element Names After Copied Or Cloned Them

Tags: jquery, dom

I am very new to JQuery and need some help. Let me explain what I want to do.

This is my table

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add">
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr id="r1" style="display:none">
        <td>
            <a href="#" onClick="$(this).removeRow();">Delete</a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select id="ddlCol_1_1" name="ddlCol_1_1">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlOp_1_1" name="ddlOp_1_1">
                <option value="=">=</option>
                <option value=">">></option>
                <option value="<"><</option>
                <option value="">*</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="cond_1_1" name="cond_1_1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlConjunction_1_1" name="ddlConjunction_1_1" onChange="checkORCondition(this);">
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>
            </select>
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the SELECT drowndown name "ddlConjunction_xxx" OnChange, it will call the Javascript function to copy couple of columns (TD) and elements inside.  This function is WORKING FINE so far as coping the elements. Here is the function doing that.

```
function checkORCondition(e)
{
    // --- Find the Current Row 
    var currRow = $(e).closest('tr');
    var currRowNum = currRow.index();

    var $row = ($(this).closest("tr").length + currRowNum);
    $('#table').find("tr:eq(" + $row + ")").each(function() {
        var $tds = $(this).children()
            //$row = $("<tr></tr>");
        $(this).closest("tr").append($tds.eq(1).clone()).append($tds.eq(2).clone()).append($tds.eq(3).clone()).append($tds.eq(4).clone()).appendTo($(this)).closest("tr")
    });

}
```

Basically, I am coping the the columns 1-4 columns within the current row, so it become 8 columns, 12 columns ... so on..

I like to change the IDs/Names of the first set of copied columns 5-8 name like from "ddlCol_1_1", "ddlOp_1_1", "cond_1_1", and "ddlConjunction_1_1" ... TO ... "ddlCol_1_2", "ddlOp_1_2", "cond_1_2", and "ddlConjunction_1_2", then next set of copied columns 9-12 is "ddlCol_1_3".... so on.

Hope that I clarified this little.  Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: `$(element).attr("id", "whatever")`

Comment: How do I know what element?  Lets say in the row (TR) has element ID "ddlCol_1_1", after it copied, the 2nd element same row will have the same ID "ddlCol_1_1". How can I only change the 2nd one to "ddlCol_1_2"?

Comment: var id = ($(element).attr("id")).substr(-1);
$(element).attr("id", "ddlCol_1_"+(id)+=1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this:

```
var myTbl = $('#table'), count = 1;
myTbl.eq(0).on('change', 'td select.xor', function(){
count += 1;
var tds = [];
var lastTr = $(this).closest("tr");
lastTr.find("td:gt(0):lt(5)").each(function() {
    var idArr = ($(this).find('select, input').attr('id')).split('_'); 
    var newId = idArr[0] + '_' + (count)+ '_' + (count);

    tds.push($(this).clone()
                    .find('select, input')
                    .attr('id', newId)
                    .prop('name',  newId)
                    .end());
     });
  lastTr.append(tds);
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ACirohE/2/edit)**
You can tweak it however you want it.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the DEMO @Alex. This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: One quick question, anyone! what is "myTbl.eq(0)" means?  is that mean the first row of the table?

Comment: No , eq(0) is almost the same as .get(0), or  [0], but it also gives you ability to chain other jquery functionality.

Comment: So in this case you're just grabbing a table.

Answer (score 0):

Cache it as variable.

```
var $new = $("#ddlCol_1_1").clone();
$new.attr("id", "#ddlCol_1_2");
```

Comment: I updated my orignal post to clarify of how I like to rename the new elements.  please take a look and see if you can help.  Thanks